# Computed observables are not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a observable array with 4 observable(Qty,Discount,Rate,Tax ) and 1 computed field(Total) which is (Price * Rate)-Discount + Tax. when i adding new item in array and change the value of qty,rate etc the ui update as expected however when initializing the view Model with data(some products), for those rows the ui not updated.

here is my code

```
var pList=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ProductList));
        var product = function (item) {

            var self = this;
            this.Qty = ko.observable(0);
            this.Rate = ko.observable(0);
            this.Discount = ko.observable(0);
            this.Tax = ko.observable(0);
            this.Amount = ko.computed(function () {


                return (parseFloat(self.Qty()) * parseFloat(self.Rate())) - parseFloat(  self.Discount() )+ parseFloat( self.Tax());

            },this);


            for (var f in item) {
                self[f] = ko.observable(item[f]);
            }

        };
        var productModel = function (prds) {
            var self = this;
            self.products = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(prds, function (item) {
                return new product(item);
            }));
            self.productList=pList;
            self.addProduct = function () {

                self.products.push(new product());
            };
            self.removeProduct = function (product) {

                self.products.remove(product);

            };
            self.GrossTotal = ko.computed(function () {

                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < self.products().length; i++) {

                    total += parseFloat( self.products()[i].Amount());
                }
                return total;
            });

        };


        var viewModel = new productModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Products)));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html:

```
                            <table class="table grid table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Order Qty</th>
                                        <th>Rate</th>
                                        <th>Discount</th>
                                        <th>Tax</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                        <th>Remove</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach: products">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="span4 form-control grid" style="min-width: 180px;"
                                                data-bind='options:$root.productList, value:ProductId, optionsText:"Text", optionValue:"Value",attr:{name:"Products["+$index() + "].ProductId"  } '>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                data-bind='value:Qty,attr:{ name:"Products["+$index()+"].Qty"  }' />

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                data-bind='value:Rate,attr:{ name:"Products["+$index()+"].Rate"  }' />

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                data-bind='value:Discount,attr:{ name:"Products["+$index()+"].Discount"  }' />

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                data-bind='value:Tax,attr:{ name:"Products["+$index()+"].Tax"  }' />

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                data-bind='value:Amount,attr:{ name:"Products["+$index()+"].Amount"  }' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="span-1">
                                            <a href="#" data-bind="click:$root.removeProduct">Remove</a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Count : <span data-bind="text: products().length"></span></th>
                                        <th>Qty :<span data-bind="text: TotalQty()"></span></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Discount :<span data-bind="text:DiscountTotal()"></span></th>
                                        <th>Tax :<span data-bind="text:TaxTotal()"></span></th>
                                        <th>Amount :<span data-bind="text:NetAmount()"></span></th>
                                        <th></th>

                                    </tr>


                                </tfoot>

                            </table>
```

here is the working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7j3q/1/)

any help would be appricated 
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is suspicious:

```
for (var f in item) {
    self[f] = ko.observable(item[f]);
}
```

If the item has keys which match the existing properties on the product object, then the observable properties will be over-written. Then the computed observable will end up subscribed to the old observable properties, but the new values will be stored in the new observable properties. That probably explains the strange behaviour.

I'd suggest updating the properties on the product (eg, `self[f](item[f])`) rather than replacing the observable, or to use the values from the item as the default values of the initial observables, before the computed is defined.

Comment: great, i have move computed property after the loop and that solve my problem. thanks